# Reorganizing OpenStreetMap into PostGIS database entity

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

How do I reorganize the OSM given entity to more flexible and schematic purpose?

The OSM gave 4 entities the planet_osm_line, planet_osm_point, planet_osm_polygon and planet_osm_roads.

Is there a good practice to reorganize them  like into city_building, city_road and etc?

I'll be reorganizing a city's spatial objects.

Comment: What platform will you be using? What is wrong with a good Indexing. I, and many others. render from osm2pgsql with no issues at all. You need to explain more about what you want to achieve, a Partial Index will reorganize quite nicely in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is currently no 'best practise' on how you organize the OSM data at your PostGIS backend. There are [different database schemas](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases#Database_Schemas) that are tuned for specific purposes:

- rendering
- geospatial lookups / reverse geocoding
- fulltext search / gazetter
- ...

If you have a very specific usecase, you might tweak the OSM importer mappings (e.g. at osmosis or osm2pgsql) and benefit from your tuning. But please keep in mind, that this will break the compatibility with most existing OSM tools that work with the default schemas.